# How do I get the retweet_count of a given tweet WITHOUT user interaction?

Tags: twitter, oauth

I have a list of tweets that are using a hashtag I made. I'm getting these tweets using the search api. All I want is to get the number of retweets. I DO NOT need to post on their behalf. It seams ridiculous that I would need to have every single user login to my site, login to twitter and approve my application via OAUTH for EVERY TWEET IN MY LIST. There's gotta be a way to get that number without the need for oauth.

I tried getting it directly from the search api, but that's not consistently there. I've tried https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show/275729088709283840.json but that doesn't work, for some reason. Is there anyway to do this extremely simple task without going down the asinine road of user-interaction?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a background-process that uses the stream API. Phirehose is a php library that is set up to do this: https://github.com/fennb/phirehose